# Marginal probability: Is it correct to write this

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

I have this following doubt regarding Marginal probability: Is it correct to write this?

$$
\sum\limits_{\forall y'{\rm{s}}} {p\left( {z|x,y} \right)p\left( x \right)p\left( y \right)}  = p\left( {z|x} \right)p\left( x \right)
$$
$$
\int {p\left( {z|x,y} \right)p\left( x \right)p\left( y \right)dy}  = p\left( {z|x} \right)p\left( x \right)
$$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See also [The Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). A more concise version would be obtained by removing the density $p(x)$ from the LHS and RHS, you see it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks @AdamO I understand Law of total prob., just got confused.

Comment: It seems to me you are both implicitly assuming $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Comment: yes  I am assuming x and y  independent.